# Flexbox is not taking full height in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, flexbox

`child` divs are not taking `100%` height of `flex-wrap` div only in IE11.

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-wrap {
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #ddd;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid;
  flex: 1 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="flex-wrap">
    <div class="child">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam enim, soluta dolor dolorum debitis eum id architecto iste similique eaque cum saepe, aperiam error reiciendis recusandae incidunt nihil, cupiditate quae.
    </div>
    <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque iste itaque provident ex debitis numquam minima, ratione quaerat sapiente eveniet cum quia quisquam aut deleniti explicabo ipsam nulla asperiores voluptatum?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `min-height: 100vh` to your flex-items.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-wrap {
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  background: #ddd;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid;
  flex: 1 1;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="flex-wrap">
    <div class="child">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam enim, soluta dolor dolorum debitis eum id architecto iste similique eaque cum saepe, aperiam error reiciendis recusandae incidunt nihil, cupiditate quae.
    </div>
    <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque iste itaque provident ex debitis numquam minima, ratione quaerat sapiente eveniet cum quia quisquam aut deleniti explicabo ipsam nulla asperiores voluptatum?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Added `box-sizing: border-box;` to border considered as part of `height`.

Comment: I was considering `min-height` to `child` div as last option, if there is not any proper solution.

Comment: @TalentRunners And jQuery solution is not the last option?:)

Comment: After receiving JQuery answers as duplicate, your answer seems 2nd last :D

Comment: I thought there would be any proper solution which I'm defiantly missing, but wasn't expecting jquery answers.

Comment: @TalentRunners Updated answer with another option.

Comment: Although your first option worked for me but, the second option won't work when div has overflowing (more than it's height) content, see [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rds5se84/).

Comment: @TalentRunners OK, thanks for your feedback, removed second option from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a know issue of flexbox, however one of the solution is to fix it with jquery. Something like that should work.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var heightBox =  0;
 $('.child').each(function(){
 if($(this).height()>heightBox){
  heightBox=$(this).height();
  }
 });
 $('.child').height(heightBox);
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.flex-wrap {
  display: flex;
  display: -ms-flex;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: #ddd;
}

.child {
  border: 1px solid;
  flex: 1 1;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="flex-wrap">
    <div class="child">
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quam enim, soluta dolor dolorum debitis eum id architecto iste similique eaque cum saepe, aperiam error reiciendis recusandae incidunt nihil, cupiditate quae.
    </div>
    <div class="child">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eaque iste itaque provident ex debitis numquam minima, ratione quaerat sapiente eveniet cum quia quisquam aut deleniti explicabo ipsam nulla asperiores voluptatum?</div>
  </div>
</div>
```